# URL slugs for nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, seo, friendly-url, slug

In my rails app my models include `user`, `item`, and `user_item`.

**user.rb**

```
has_many :user_items
has_many :items, through: :user_items
```

**item.rb**

```
has_many :user_items
has_many :users, -> { uniq }, through: :user_items
belongs_to :user
```

**user_item.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :item
```

Names for items should never change and cannot be edited by users.

A URL for a user would be `/users/:id`.  A URL for an item, would be `/items/:name` for SEO and user-friendly purposes.

But what would be best for `user_item`?  Some possibilities:

`/users/:id/items/:name`

`/user_item/:id`

`/user_item/:item_name`

`/user_item/:id/:item_name`

Answer (score 0):

I would refer `/items/:name/user_items/:id`

Other choices you suggested is maybe invalid, here is why:

> /users/:id/items/:name

=> Only logged in user can access the `user_item`, so `/users/:id` is redundant, otherwise, this kind of url doesn't point to `user_item`

> /user_item/:id

=> This is okay, but should be changed to `/user_items/:id', but this is not friendly as you want

> /user_item/:item_name

=> This doesn't make sense, since an `item_name` may have many `user_items`(s)

> /user_item/:id/:item_name

=> This doesn't make sense as well because `id` is enough to identify an `user_item`